# Whats the best practice to store Date object in the database when use with API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been seeing people store UTC Date object in the database and return as string, but recently I am start seeing people store and return as numbers (milliseconds). What's the best approach?

Comment: In JS numbers use 8 bytes. If you convert a date to a string it will probably occupy more space.

Comment: Storing a number means devs aren't tempted to use unreliable parsing to convert to a Date object. Using `new Date(timevalue)` is very much more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not mentioned the database you used in your case. I just want to mention `Mongodb` through `Node.js`, one thing I am suffering is that has no real concept of timezones for `UTC Date()` or numbers (milliseconds) in JavaScript. If I had been storing `UTC dates` in MongoDB, for example a `Date()` object, but it's unexpectedly complicated and error-prone to converted it to the timezone they are happened to. As a result, I've decided to use simple strings like the good old Date string standard `yyyy-mm-dd::hh::mm::ss` to store date time, and I'll parse into `Date()` objects as needed in the client side.

Comment: @cjskywalker, per this [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html), it would be ok to use `TIMESTAMP` string 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' as I mentioned in MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

suggest you define a standard between the code and the database about the defination of time.  no matter what, if it is convenient for you the parse or store, the solution is the best.